# Neo4j SDN4 and a correct usage of internal Ids

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I read that using a Neo4j internal Ids for external purpose is a not a good practice.

I think I have made a mistake in my SDN4/Neo4j application because I'm using internal ids everywhere.

Every SDN 4 node entity in my application have a following property:

```
@GraphId
private Long id;
```

I use this long value as a part of my web application urls.. for example

```
/products/3245234
```

where `3245234` is an internal Neo4j identifier for this product node entity.

Is it safe from Neo4j point of view - to use internal IDs in such way ? If no, could you please provide an example how a new surrogate keys can solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Eric has said is correct when it comes to how Neo4j internal ID's are able to be recycled.

We have started to add support to SDN to help developers get around this.  We can do this by way of a few examples.

**Example 1: When you have a natural ID**

Let's say we have a `User` domain object and it is uniquely identifiable by a field called `email`. We might set up our model like so:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique=true, primary=true)
    private String email;

    ... 

}
```

We can then have a repository set up as such:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {

}
```

Notice how the last value in the parameterized type is a String. This represents the primary index used for this class.

You can now do something like:

```
User user = userRepository.findOne("john.doe@email.com");
```

See how you can just pass in the primary ID for the class?

**Example 2: When you need a synthetic ID**

Let's say the user we defined above has Tweets. Since there is no natural ID for a tweet we give it one. The best way to avoid ID collisions it to use a type 4 UUID.  Luckily Java comes pre packed with UUID and SDN supports persistence of it.

```
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;
import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.UuidStringConverter;
import java.util.UUID;

@NodeEntity
public class Tweet {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
    @Index(unique = true, primary = true)
    private UUID uuid;

    ...

    public Tweet(String message) {
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        // other initialisation.
    }
}
```

So what we have here is a `UUID` assigned to any created Tweet. This can then be saved to the database via the converter.  The handy thing about this is that there are no extra libraries to install. It is also guaranteed (well, for the most part!) to never have the problems that the internal Neo4j ID's have.  The pro (or con) is that ID's are manufactured to be universally unique by your application code.

If you are keen to have the database always generate the UUID then I would also recommend the GraphAware https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid plugin.

Again the Tweet Repository can take advantage of this:

```
public interface TweetRepository extends CrudRepository<Tweet, UUID> {

}
```

You can now do something like:

```
Tweet tweet = tweetRepository.findOne(UUID.fromString("0f6e7004-cefc-4397-b4d2-078c1370856a"));
```

*A final note; at the time of writing `@Indexed(unique=true,primary=true)` may be changed to simply be called `@Id` in SDN 5.0.*

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! One follow-up question regarding the Cypher query and `UUID`. Previously as a params to my Cypher query I used `Ids(@GraphId)` and a following statements - for example where `WHERE ID(p) in {productIds}`.. Right now instead of internal IDs I have to pass a set of `UUID`. How to correctly use these `UUID` in Cypher - `ID(p) IN {productUUIDs}` or simlpe `p IN {productUUIDs}`. Also, are any difference from a performance point of view  between `GraphId` and `@Index(unique = true, primary = true) private UUID uuid`?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `WHERE p.uuid IN {productUuids}` where the `productUuids` are the String representations. I'm not sure if we support parameter conversion of repository methods at the moment but we will in the next release. Regarding performance, if you turn on autoindexing or you have already indexed the uuid property of that label then it should be very fast as the lookups are done via indexes.

Answer (score 4):

From an application view, using Neo4j internal id’s is safe, in that nothing in your application will break by using them.

That said, Neo4j internal id’s are recycled, by which I mean if a node or relationship has an internal id of 12345 and at some point that node or relationship is deleted, the id of 12345 becomes eligible for reuse by a future node or relationship. I believe it wise to assume the newly available id will be reused at some point in the future. This has the negative side effect of that Neo4j internal id’s are not considered “stable” and should not be used outside of your application.

As for an example of a new surrogate key, I would point you toward GraphAware’s neo4j-uuid project at https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid. This Neo4j plugin can be used to automatically create a unique and stable UUID on all nodes and relationships that will not and can not be changed or updated.